# Right hand side blinkers on Holden/Opel Barina not working

Tags: electrical, barina, opel

The right hand side blinkers in my 2005 Holden/Opel Barina stopped working.
When I turn the blinkers on they do the right click-click sound just much faster than usual.
All 3 blinkers stopped working.
I've checked the front and rear bulbs and are good. I've checked the fuse and it's good.
I've measured the voltage on the metal contacts at the back and there is no voltage at all.

Where should I start looking for the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One other thing to check is to see if one of the smaller turn signal bulbs are out. When any of the bulbs are out, the turn signal will blink faster. You may have one or more marker lights on the side of the car which function as a turn signal light. If out, this could be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the bulbs are good, the fuses are good (both in the engine compartment and inside the vehicle, and the flasher is good (the clicking sound maker), then I would say the turn signal switch.  However, to properly diagnosis that, you will want to get a wiring diagram.

Other, less likely items would be a bad ground, bad wiring, or bad connection somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test to narrow it down a bit - do the three bulbs light when you put the hazard-warning lights on?

If so, my first culprit would be the switch, and if not, a wiring fault...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Barina has two different flashers (relays) one for each side that are installed behind the batter compartment in the most inaccessible place possible.
One of these relays was broken. Had to buy another one and replace it and they are all working now.
The clicking noise is done by some other component from what I see as it was clicking nicely and even the lights on the dashboard were blinking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem with my 2005 Holden Astra ended up being the flash cam you can fix it if you take it out pullout the inside and just clean out the points you got contact points to make a clicking sound and clean them out and put it back in and should work if not buy new flash cam you can tell this is the problem because when you pull it out  you won't have any indicators and the emergency flashing light will work only on the inside of the car not  the outside

Comment: Could you edit this with some punctuation? This is nearly unreadable.